# jquery reading nested json

Tags: jquery, json, nested

I have the following json as seen below. I'm trying to read the values TOP1, TOP2. I'm a little unsure of how to do this.

I'm using the following .. But that just gets me an object which has the nested objects for TOP1 and TOP2. How do I get the values  TOP1 and TOP2 ??

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/data/menufixed.json',
    function(data) {            
        $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
            var html = '<li class="top-level">';

        });
    });
```

And the data below

```
{
"actions" : [
    {
        "action": "TOP1",
        "subaction": [
            {
                "name": "A" 
            },
            {
                "name": "B" 
            },
            {
                "name": "C" 
            } 
        ] 
    },
    {
        "action": "TOP2",
        "subaction": [
            {
                "name": "X" 
            },
            {
                "name": "Y" 
            } 
        ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you want to loop though the `.actions`, so change this:

```
$.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry) {
  var html = '<li class="top-level">';
});
```

To this:

```
$.each(data.actions, function(entryIndex, entry) {
  var html = '<li class="top-level">' + this.action + '</li>';
});
```

Using `data.actions` you're now looping through that array of objects, and *those* objects are the ones with the `.action` property, for example: `"TOP1"` and `"TOP2"`.

Comment: This is what im after thanks Nick! How might I access the ABC / YX data ?

Comment: @imerez - *Inside* the `$.each()` callback above, you would do `$.each(this.subaction, function() { alert(this.name); });`, that would give you A, B, C, etc. - test it out here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mHvvA/2/

Comment: Thanks thats what Im after .. thanks for the excellent resource jsfiddle also :P

Answer (score 1):

After 10 years i'm answering this equation. Using multidimensional array of objects, the inner value can be retrieved.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(data.actions, function(i, elementText) { 
    displayHTML += '<div><h2>' +elementText.action+ '</h2></div>';

  $.each(elementText.subaction, function(j, elementSubText) { 
  displayHTML += '<li><span>' +elementSubText.name+'</span></li>';
  });
});
$("#listing").append(displayHTML);
});
```

Here is the fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/h9vxeuzn/ - [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/h9vxeuzn/)