# reading nested JSON via AJAX with jquery or javascript and outputting to tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery reading nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017122/jquery-reading-nested-json)

I would really like to have a hard and fast method to loop through multiple records in JSON, each with potentially deep nesting. I simply want to output to a table.

I am unsure of what arguments need to be passed through the function() for either $.each() or for the javascript methodology of $.ajax() success. All examples seem to use generic words "data" or "obj" but those confuse me - are they built-in functional arguments or can I name them whatever I want like:

```
$.each(foo, function(bar){

});
```

And how can I keep track of where I am in the loop / nest?

I would prefer to use JQuery, but I should also know the straight-forward JavaScript method to do so. And I'd also like to know if it's possible without a hundred lines of code.

With this JSON as an example:

```
{
  date: " 2012-10-18 16:58:35.104576",
  data: [{
    title: "The Princess Bride",
    rating: "PG",
    length: 128,
    stars: [
      "Gary Elwes",
      "Robin Wright",
      "Christopher Guest"
    ]

  }, {
    title: "This is Spinal Tap",
    rating: "R",
    length: 105,
    stars: [
      "Christopher Guest",
      "Michael McKean",
      "Harry Shearer"
    ]
  }]
}
```

I can't find any useful examples that include nested JSON, even here in the StackOverflow.

what's the most efficient way to loop through and assign each element to a table cell? The HTML output is not important - I know how to make a table... How do I get the "stars"?

When I use the Chrome console and simply `$.getJSON('/example');` I get the entire JSON returned in the responseText, starting with `"{"date":"2012-10-18 ,"data": [{"title": "The Princess Bride",` However in neither the JSON docs, the JQuery docs on $.getJSON, nor in any JavaScript examples can I find a reference to `responseText`. So, I'm lost. What argument does $.getJSON need to objectify the responseText?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, you'll want to parse it. Try `var myData = JSON.parse(responseText);` You might find it helpful to output it to the console, too: `console.log(myData)` Then you can do something like `var someStars = myData.data[0].stars;`
Let me know if you have any questions about looping through your data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try

```
obj.data[0].stars      // Will get you the stars in the 1st Object

obj.data[0].stars[0]   // Gary Elwes
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UwHxq/)

To iterate thru the Stars object You can try this

```
$.each(obj.data , function(key , value){ // First Level
    $.each(value.stars , function(k , v ){  // The contents inside stars
        console.log(v)
    });        

});
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/UwHxq/1/)

**EDIT**

```
 $.ajax({
      // Parameters 

      success : function(obj){
            $.each(obj.data , function(key , value){ // First Level
                 $.each(value.stars , function(k , v ){  // The contents inside stars
                     console.log(v)
                 });     
            });
      }
  });
```

Comment: What if the JSON is coming in via AJAX? How can I assign var obj via AJAX?

Comment: Check edited post.. You object will be in the callback of your Ajax request

Comment: When I do:
`
$.ajax({
 url:'/example',
 dataType:'json',
 success: function(obj){
  $.each(obj.data, function(key, value){
    $.each(value.stars, function(k,v){
      alert(v);
    });
  });
 }
});
`
I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
I wish I could figure out how to debug this myself, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the console section for any errors .. What does the request and response show in the console.. Also set type: 'POST' for your ajax request

Comment: it's the console saying `Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, and expanding the error in Chrome console there's an `(anonymous function)` in my JSON script on the line with `$.each(value.stars, function(k,v){`

Comment: is there an index missing from this function?

Comment: Check the request and response data... Also try commenting your loops and try console.log(obj)  .. What do you see??

Comment: This is cool: the console.log(obj); with the request of 'POST' results in a 404 error, changing to 'GET' comes back with:
`data:Array[7]` (using live data, there are 7 records)

Each index displays `> 0:Object > 1:Object` and so-on. However, I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when I restore the second each loop, `$.each(value.stars, function(k,v){alert(v);}); because, as it turns out, the live data uses an underscore before the stars Array. So, this error is resulting from a typo. Changing `stars` to `_stars` alleviates this issue, alerts ensue.

Comment: @Sushanth-- Thanks for your answer. It works for me. I have tried many solution but your solution works. uprated. Thanks